# Ruby on Rails and MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rubygems, mongodb-ruby

I have a new Ruby on Rails installation where I can see the default start-page.

I followed [this guide](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started) in order to install MongoDB to Rails.

Now I get this error when running `rake test`:

```
**Notice: C extension not loaded. This is required for optimum MongoDB Ruby driver performance.
  You can install the extension as follows:
  gem install bson_ext

  If you continue to receive this message after installing, make sure that the
  bson_ext gem is in your load path and that the bson_ext and mongo gems are of the same version.
```

I have installed the bson_ext gem, which means that now bson_ext in not in my load path or that the gems are not the same version.

Where is the load path? How can I change it?
How do I check if the gems are the same version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Ruby on Rails 3+, you should check that the bson_ext gem is referenced in your Gemfile.

Comment: It is not, how do I add it? Sorry but I'm new to Rails. Switching from long term relationship with PHP =)

Comment: Ok I think this fixed it: `gem "bson_ext"`. Thanks!

Comment: In your gemfile add the line `gem "bson_ext"` and then run `bundle update` from your command line.

Comment: Yep, you got it.  You can either run `bundle update` as @theTRON mentioned, or `bundle install`.

Answer (score 2):

Open up Gemfile (in your rails app's root directory) and add a line that says: `bson_ext`

You should have:

```
gem mongo
gem bson_ext
```

Also here is some more info from [10gen docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started#Rails3-GettingStarted-RunningTests) on running tests in rails:

> Running Tests
>   A slight modification is required to get rake test working (thanks to John P. Wood). Create a file lib/tasks/mongo.rake containing the following:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :prepare do
      # Stub out for MongoDB
    end
  end
end
```

> Now the various rake test tasks will run properly. See John's post for more details.

They also reference [John Wood's post](http://johnpwood.net/2010/04/13/getting-rake-test-running-with-rails-3-and-mongodb/) which is quite good.

Comment: You are referring to the same article as the one in my question.